# How can I find the minimum of this functional?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, maxima-minima, calculus-of-variations

**The problem:**

Define

$$F(x,z,p) := |p|^q - z^2 + \log(1+z^2)$$

where $\log$ denotes the natural logarithm and $q > 1$. Define

$$\mathscr{F}(u) := \int_0^1F(x,u(x),u'(x)) \, {\rm d} x$$

for every $u \in W^{1,1}([0,1])$ such that $u(0)=0$ and $u(1)=1$.

I would like to know if the *minimum* of $\mathscr{F}$ exists.

---

**My attempt:**

First of all $F \in C^{\infty}$ and is convex in $p$.

I tried defining $F_k(x,z,p)=F(x,z,p)$ if $|z|\leq k$ and $F(x,k,p)$ if $|z|\geq k$ and studying first the functional $F_k$ but I cannot reach any conclusion.

Any hint or help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no x in the definition of F ?

Comment: This functional is unbounded below on that set

Comment: @Velobos No, there is not.

Comment: @s.harp Can you explain to me how can you say that $\mathscr{F}$ is unbounded below? Do you think it happens even if $q>2$?

Comment: @FilippoGiovagnini ah, I misread the definition completely. Nevermind my comment.

Comment: @s.harp Don't worry.